# Plotting two sets of data againnst one another in r

Tags: r

Hi I am attempting to plot 2 sets of data that relate against each other,

One on the Y and the other on the X

for example here are my sets of data:

```
df1 = structure(list(CS1 = c(0.275452524610988, 0.0890234670704012, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ), CS2 =
  c(0.273041018387553, 0.158963204640203, 0.107973506559674, 
  0.127130301872373, 0.194176156840133, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA), CS3 = c(0.13740676993689, 0.109451540195342, 
  0.142863368925692, 0.14583878810548, 0.163760683760684, 0.144456538640958, 
  0.0675847193993944, 0.14371051120046, 0.173233830845771, 0.176593446164926, 
  0.161520678140252, 0.15704679566351, 0.15038404968132, 0.111057167131934, 
  0.090005047955578, 0.0904423812124522, 0.139732920456745, 0.101917044266295, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ), CS4 = c(0.180049261083744, 0.210920756262371,
  0.207122726108122, 
  0.102897135416667, 0.0978761658613327, 0.203262051467923, 0.45636403605188, 
  0.14423587969798, 0.166896927831303, 0.152883086450749, 0.258352200019687, 
  0.0430782684739834, 0.167648827420325, 0.0810183353119641, 0.25995907837381, 
  0.11673133987674, 0.110546066252588, 0.130632135895294, 0.142066731454487, 
  0.0756522704563118, 0.303907946157186, 0.159501557632399, 0.170402871958516, 
  0.133117551861115, 0.155054586700695, 0.164944275582574, 0.223909531502423, 
  0.160357391800266, 0.257635675220867, 0.15363303711448, 0.226395631067961, 
  0.0953366226325004, 0.167523252469077, 0.161264071612641), CS6 = c(0.174656417423713, 
  0.180655066530195, 0.038575363525719, 0.140051238257899, 0.200724929520741, 
  0.159254670224933, 0.16012350077188, 0.176349710442742, 0.163041789128746, 
  0.159630016410562, 0.194189328743546, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CS7 =
  c(0.161839193508729, 0.119446786979255, 0.186711807024968, 
  0.0900905700586042, 0.221011032438663, 0.0524430272906312, 0.214230867673407, 
  0.109561723342511, 0.191344988748485, 0.138885983263598, 0.19734564339296, 
  0.111221877946922, 0.240647749220027, 0.182876881322477, 0.171344685848503, 
  0.183018867924528, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CS8 = c(0.208645229309436, 0.168562833310543,
  0.161180007515971, 0.122041517916171, 0.133028106320743, 0.249202264539372, 
  0.194792833146697, 0.157660991857883, 0.105321703956516, 0.102024877061036, 
  0.0838767042086544, 0.311601536304335, 0.191905094207955, 0.127657464043644, 
  0.061887744376708, 0.169011882426517, 0.19027015154843, 0.159290431179593, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ), CS9 = c(0.111283891547049, 0.123824130879346,
  0.20258885476086, 
  0.150561330561331, 0.158708927013667, 0.203820631409612, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CS10 = c(0.163579343508258, 
  0.184119010819165, 0.0385607528369776, 0.151343315280875, 0.110706817231284, 
  0.104659986379998, 0.205260047281324, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
  NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"))

df2 = structure(list(CS1 = c(7.1855827246745, -2.89023467070401, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
  CS2 = c(14.4918811881188, 7.40119630233823, 5.52194624888549, 
  2.14197554451662, 8.22580366152515, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CS3 = c(9.75146299483649, 
  4.84006010518407, 7.79873610808455, 11.9482326538246, 9.54301117685733, 
  8.90216140569118, 4.41407773030818, 11.1924181504882, 13.332504145937, 
  9.59668707238027, 12.8002226217998, 8.91395636064224, 7.68370648798823, 
  4.97487559169802, -0.302675416456332, 3.92422173675587, 5.21019289078124, 
  1.94964563727199, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CS4 = c(10.5336382828994, 12.2885809842332, 
  12.5569049449142, 5.01982421875, 3.20047196314192, 9.04392895976803, 
  20.0755330841943, 4.80978613911503, 5.8746591528813, 6.68753870616788, 
  10.1209371001083, -0.944521206821163, 9.55786730807777, 0.931829573934837, 
  13.6828929810515, 2.253868979685, 6.06061076604555, 2.20153160679477, 
  2.4557045675413, 2.63630509603642, 9.88050369083804, 0.0527677929547089, 
  6.48542746975137, 1.41274091510961, 7.29614348504183, 7.68493269648285, 
  11.5562548289668, 7.19918889804195, 15.3076146403029, -0.0899111343439618, 
  10.3047330097087, 1.39891771446761, 7.78885799213731, 6.10031194900312
  ), CS6 = c(4.1787095271372, 4.62118730808597, -0.587060406123888, 
  5.64545972103615, 7.99747617129816, 9.49651162790698, 4.8287376796105, 
  7.29071548664301, 5.89087530826661, 5.75097717439953, 6.74011703958692, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CS7 = c(4.71177772313745, 
  1.37851239669421, -3.13076597545493, 2.24620848872314, -0.832965585377901, 
  -0.0889243177342196, 10.0609163040696, 1.40906317434333, 
  4.13460273498356, 2.71950836820084, 8.28693979611464, 4.9104674659841, 
  10.7405437527856, 13.4829015544041, 4.56230182031709, 0.759141184124919, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA), CS8 = c(15.3824986821297, 11.5551620402024, 
  9.1133659025429, 4.7955573185244, 8.96281317563271, 18.8155944415852, 
  8.72687569988802, 7.86902294596595, 6.24227025660473, 4.60072317037894, 
  3.37021339656194, 12.2052673291471, 7.98692719237032, 2.45028930401719, 
  0.815415878354706, 11.8678236397749, 8.01842741049857, 7.1366049462644, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA), CS9 = c(3.4109649122807, 5.76513292433538, 13.5378236068451, 
  5.73596673596674, 4.87345158476301, 21.4396541323145, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CS10 = c(5.11039096801171, 
  5.42426584234931, 1.2306670357044, 9.22986088988, 2.97189460476788, 
  5.26471446638778, 7.09148936170213, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: (a) Thank you for posting reproducible data. (b) What have you tried and where are you stuck? (c) Each of your data sets have 10 columns, but your text doesn't mention these at all. What do they mean? Do they need to be considered or used in the answer? (d) I do appreciate your reproducible example, but I'd suggest making a **minimal** reproducible example. Probably the problem and solution could be demonstrated on the first 8 rows of the first 3 columns? Next time consider sharing something like `dput(data1[1:8, 1:3])` instead of the whole big thing.

Comment: HI, so Im looking to plot CS1 from one set against the other set of datas CS1 and so on to compare if there is a shift in the data sets. I am sorry about the formatting. I have tried
 y <- Ft_max_02_030615
x <-int_02_030615
  
  plot(x, y, col = "red")
without a effect I was hoping for

Comment: Do you want them all in the same plot? Or one column per plot in 10 different plots? If different plots, do you want them visible together on the same page, or completely separate? If not different plots, how do you want to distinguish between the different columns?

Comment: The same plot would be very helpful I believe. and yes being able to tell the differemce between the different CS's would be amazing

Comment: Also, I removed the Excel tag because nothing in your question indicates you want a solution in Excel. Don't add tags just because they're suggested - only add them if they are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `tidyverse`. The datasets are saved in `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  bind_rows( rownames_to_column(df2), .id="set") %>% 
  gather(k,v,-set, -rowname) %>%   
  mutate(set = paste0("set",set)) %>% 
  spread(set, v) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(set1, set2, color=k)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    # add regression lines?!
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F,show.legend = F, size=0.5)
```

[image]

Of course you can use a facet panel as suggested in the comments.

```
df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  bind_rows( rownames_to_column(df2), .id="set") %>% 
  gather(k,v,-set, -rowname) %>%   
  mutate(set = paste0("set",set)) %>% 
  spread(set, v) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(set1, set2, color=k)) + 
    geom_point(show.legend = F) + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F,show.legend = F) + 
    facet_wrap(~k, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Despite OP's claims in the comments, I think `facet_wrap(~k)` would be a lot more readable than the colors.

Comment: @Gregor great idea. Added this feature as well.

Comment: How would I add the second data set into this? What I'm looking to do is compare data set 1 on the Y and data saet 2 on the X. Thank you very much Jimbou

Comment: @user3478013 are you kidding me? This is exactly what my solution is doing

Comment: Sorry my eyes didnt see that. My bad, Its been a long day, Thank you

Comment: Any way I can get lines into the first plot? Rather than individual pannels?

Comment: @user3478013 "*Any way I can get lines into the first plot? Rather than individual pannels?*" Did you try? What did you try? There's one line of code that makes lines, and one line of code that makes the panels. If you only have the line code, you'll have lines with no panels. Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

With first structure -> x, second structure -> y, then

```
plot(unlist(x), unlist(y))
```